# Convert/Format String to Int (Time to Hours)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Database Table

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| Time                                      |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 6 Days 12 Hours 35 Minutes 7 Seconds      |
| 4 Days 10 Hours 12 Minutes 0 Seconds      |
| 10 Hours 12 Minutes 0 Seconds             | 
| 12 Hours 35 Minutes 7 Seconds             | 
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Create new column in MS SQL server as "Hours" and convert the "Time" column values to hours.

**Example:** if we convert "6 Days 12 Hours 35 Minutes 7 Seconds" manually to Hours it will be 156.58 Hours. We need to update Hours Column with respective hours.

```
+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| Time                                      | Hours      |
+-------------------------------------------+------------+
| 6 Days 12 Hours 35 Minutes 7 Seconds      |            |
| 4 Days 10 Hours 12 Minutes 0 Seconds      |            |
| 10 Hours 12 Minutes 0 Seconds             |            |
| 12 Hours 35 Minutes 7 Seconds             |            |
+-------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Looks like homework which you are required to show us your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little ugly.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Yw5JyENO)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Time] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('6 Days 12 Hours 35 Minutes 7 Seconds')
,('4 Days 10 Hours 12 Minutes 0 Seconds')
,('10 Hours 12 Minutes 0 Seconds')
,('12 Hours 35 Minutes 7 Seconds')
 
Select A.*
      ,Hrs = (
       IsNull(try_convert(int,JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')) * try_convert(int,JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')),0)
      +IsNull(try_convert(int,JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')) * try_convert(int,JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')),0)
      +IsNull(try_convert(int,JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]')) * try_convert(int,JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[5]')),0)
      +IsNull(try_convert(int,JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[6]')) * try_convert(int,JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[7]')),0)
      )/3600.0
  From @YourTable A
  Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(replace(string_escape(replace(replace(replace(replace([Time],'Days','86400'),'Hours','3600'),'Minutes','60'),'Seconds','1'),'json'),' ','_'),'_','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

```
Time                                    Hrs
6 Days 12 Hours 35 Minutes 7 Seconds    156.585277
4 Days 10 Hours 12 Minutes 0 Seconds    106.200000
10 Hours 12 Minutes 0 Seconds           10.200000
12 Hours 35 Minutes 7 Seconds           12.585277
```